# What does this "Lambda Expression" do?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, matchevaluator

Just come across the following line of code and having a hard time finding documentation for it, is it a `lambda expression`? What does this do?

```
temp = Regex.Replace(url, REGEX_COOKIE_REPLACE,match => cookie.Values[match.Groups["CookieVar"].Value]);
```

Specifically interested in the `=>`.

Comment: It's [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy.aspx) - that's a lambda, yes, to specify the [MatchEvaluator delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator.aspx).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for Replace, the 3rd argument is a `MatchEvaluator`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator.aspx

This is a delegate that takes a `Match` as an argument and returns the string to replace it with. Your code is defining a `MatchEvaluator` using a lambda expression:

```
match => cookie.Values[match.Groups["CookieVar"].Value]
```

Here, for each match that the Regex finds, a value is being looked up in the `cookie.Values` dictionary and the result is being used as the replacement.

Answer (score 7):

```
match => cookie.Values[match.Groups["CookieVar"].Value]
```

is a shortcut to

```
delegate (Match match)
{
    return cookie.Values[match.Groups["CookieVar"].Value];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `RegEx.Replace` runs the lambda for every match of `REGEX_COOKIE_REPLACE` in `url` and "replaces" the match with the lambdas result.

The lambda (or shorthand delegate)

```
match => cookie.Values[match.Groups["CookieVar"].Value]
```

uses the `Value` of the "CookieVar"`Group,`of the`Match,`to look up a substitution in the`cookie.Values`collection. The lookup value replaces the match.

To tell you more about the "CookieVar" group we would need to see an evaluation of `REGEX_COOKIE_REPLACE.`